# How to modify Frame parameter of current page in Universal app for Windows 10

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

A Universal app for Windows 10 uses a `Frame` to navigate different `Page`s. Some of those pages have parameters, e.g., a product identifier, that tell them what to display. Such parameters are passed to `Frame.Navigate()`.

On occasion I navigate to a page using imperfect information. I then use that information to look up *additional* information that tells me what to display. I'd like to update the navigation parameter with this additional information to avoid re-doing the look-up when the user navigates backwards or forwards.

My initial idea was simply to diddle with the `PageStackEntry` at the top of the `Frame`'s `BackStack`, something along these lines:

```
IList<PageStackEntry> stack = frame.ForwardStack;
if (stack.Count > 0)
{
    PageStackEntry stackEntry = stack[stack.Count - 1];

    // PageStackEntry properties don't have setters, so create a new entry:
    stack[stack.Count - 1] = new PageStackEntry(
        stackEntry.SourcePageType,
        (my updated parameter goes here),
        stackEntry.NavigationTransitionInfo);
}
```

It turns out, however, that the `BackStack` doesn't include the current page. (Nor does the `ForwardStack`.) If there's any `PageStackEntry` that describes the current page, I don't know where it is.

My only other idea is to call `GetNavigationState()`, tamper with the resulting string (which *does* include a description of the state of the current page), then call `SetNavigationState()`. I hesitate to do that, since [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.getnavigationstate.aspx) states that the serialization format is officially undefined:

> The serialization format used by these methods is for internal use only. Your app should not form any dependencies on it. Additionally, this format supports serialization only for basic types like string, char, numeric and GUID types.

An example of a serialized navigation state looks like this (for a single page); figuring out the details of the format should be doable:

```
1,1,0,60,MyApp.UX.Pages.MyPage,12,34,{"Data":{"PrimaryParameter":"42"}},0
```

But "**your app should not form any dependencies on the format**" sounds...offputting, to say the least. I'd be glad of any thoughts and suggestions on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think pass parameter around like that is a good ideal. There are more adaptive ways to solve that, one of them is create a parameter class to hold data, pass it when navigating, and cast it to correct type at the landing Page.

Comment: That part isn't the problem; navigation works fine. I'm looking for a nice way to update the parameter in the navigation stack.

Comment: I think you can setup a flag, so when navigating forward, you get the additional data, set the flag to true, when navigating back, check if the flag is there or not.

Comment: To be sure. That's not the question, though: is there a nice/clean way to modify the parameter of the current page in a Frame's navigation state?